# Transport is not working for send Auto Email

Tags: android, email, transport

I am trying to send a Auto-Email on button click ,for that i call sendEmail() method from xml

```
android:onClick="sendEmail"
```

and

```
    m = new Mail("blue@gmail.com", "####Password");
```

In abov line i am calling a mail constructor of Mail Class

my sendEmail method is as follow-

```
       public void sendEmail(View view){ 
    String[] toArr = {"blue@gmail.com"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
    m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
    m.setFrom("blue@gmail.com"); // who is sending the email
    m.setSubject("subject");
    m.setBody("your message goes here");
     System.out.println(" Inside sendmail");
    try {
    //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg"); // path to file you want to attach 
    if(m.send()) {
    // success
    Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
    // failure
    Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    } catch(Exception e) {
    // some other problem
    Toast.makeText(AutomaticEmailActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }
```

My Mail Class is as follow -

```
        package com.kt.email;


      import java.sql.Date;
      import java.util.Properties;

      import javax.activation.CommandMap;
      import javax.activation.DataHandler;
      import javax.activation.DataSource;
      import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
     import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
     import javax.mail.BodyPart;
     import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
      import javax.mail.Session;
     import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
     import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


     public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;
private Properties _properties;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public Mail() {
_host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
_port = "993"; // default smtp port
_sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port
_properties = new Properties();
_user = ""; // username
_pass = ""; // password
_from = ""; // email sent from
_subject = ""; // email subject
_body = ""; // email body  

_debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
_auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

_multipart = new MimeMultipart();

// There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}

public Mail(String user, String pass) {
this();

_user = user;
_pass = pass;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Begning of send method");
Properties props = _setProperties();

if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("inside if of send method");
javax.mail.Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
System.out.println("inside if before for loop of send method");

for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
System.out.println("inside if inside for loop of send method");

}
msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

msg.setSubject(_subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date(0));

// setup message body
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
System.out.println("inside if after body of send method");

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
System.out.println("1");

// Put parts in message 
msg.setContent(_multipart);
System.out.println("2");


// send email
 Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
 transport.connect(this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), 
         Integer.parseInt(this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.port")),
         this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
         this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    System.out.println("3");

 transport.sendMessage(msg, addressTo); 
//Transport.send(msg);
System.out.println("3");

System.out.println("End of send method");


return true;
} else {
    System.out.println("inside else of send method");

return false;
}

}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

//@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

if(_debuggable) {
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
}

if(_auth) {
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
}

props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
this._body = _body;
}

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
this._to = toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
this._from = string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
this._subject = string;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
```

}
In the above code of Mail Class i think mail that problem is in below code section -

```
      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
 transport.connect(this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"), 
         Integer.parseInt(this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.port")),
         this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.user"),
         this._properties.getProperty("mail.smtp.password"));
    System.out.println("3");

 transport.sendMessage(msg, addressTo);
```

But where is problem i did not get yet. I am not receiving any log-cat output.
please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          String to = textTo.getText().toString();
          String message = textMessage.getText().toString();

          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");
          myoncreate1();
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        }

    });
```